# Linq - Locally Distinct

Tags: c#, linq

Linq is pretty powerful, but sometimes I can find myself rushing to make extensions and I later wonder if I could do it with native methods.

So, is it possible to implement the following without using an extension?

```
/// <summary>
/// Removes duplicates that are immediately clustered together.
/// </summary>
public static IEnumerable<TData> DistinctLocal<TData>(this IEnumerable<TData> enumerable)
{
    bool yielded = false;
    TData last = default(TData);

    foreach (var item in enumerable)
    {
        if (yielded == false || last.Equals(item) == false)
        {
            last = item;
            yielded = true;
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would go with your extension method. I'd prefer to call it `DistinctContiguous` instead of `DistinctLocal` for clarity.

Comment: `LINQ` is just built from `native core stuff`, so of course the answer is `yes`. However looks like your code doesn't work? Why not talk a little about your code? how it works? What do you want more? BTW, I didn't even understand what you mean by `Local` until read the Douglas' comment

Comment: This is a posibility: `items.Where((x, i) => ((i == 0) || !items[i - 1].Equals(x)));`

Comment: @MeirionHughes This is true only if `items` has an indexer.

Comment: Yeah, Douglas's answer is better

Comment: Another name would be `CollapseAdjacentEqualElements`. Longer, but more descriptive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how it can be done in plain LINQ:

```
int[] source = new[] { 3, 6, 1, 8, 4, 1, 1, 1, 7, 4, 2, 2 };
var result = source.Where((x, i) => i == 0 || !x.Equals(source.ElementAt(i - 1)));
```

However, this code should only be used when the underlying sequence implements an efficient indexer for handling the `ElementAt` call, ideally in O(1) time. This is typically the case for `IList<T>` implementations, such as arrays, but not for other collections, such as `LinkedList<T>`.

Additionally, if you need to use this functionality regularly, there's nothing wrong with defining an extension method, which would be more maintainable than scattering this code (or any equivalent) all over the place. I would personally prefer to use your own extension method to avoid the risk of the performance issue on non-indexed collections.

Comment: Yes, `ElementAt` typically translates to an indexer for `IList<T>` implementations.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in method that will give you exactly the functionality you want, but obviously you can cobble together a solution using only LINQ and some hackish code.

**However**: An extension method with a good descriptive name is going to be far far better than (ab)using built-in methods or functionality to give you this. My advice: *go with the extension method*.

However, here's a non-extension method hackish way to obtain the same results, you can test this in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net):

```
void Main()
{
    var source = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1 };

    int? prev = null;
    (from value in source
     where !prev.HasValue || prev.Value != value
     let dummy = prev = value
     select value).Dump();
}
```

Comment: Note that since I don't consider the code above as usable in production code, I did not bother making it able to handle things that cannot compare using the `==` operator, etc.

Comment: This relies on side-effects, which is discouraged in LINQ.

Comment: Yes, I know. I would consider this an academic result, ie. "can it be done". It should definitely *not be done* this way.

Comment: Since we agree you should not rely on side-effects, let's at least compress this code into an one-liner: `source.Where(c => { var f = c != prev; prev = c; return f; })` :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Aggregate`:

```
source.Aggregate(new List<YourType>(), 
     (items, current) => 
     {
        if (!items.Any() || items.Last() != current)
            items.Add(current);
        return items;
     });
```

But obviously it would consume your sequence so you'll lose laziness...

Comment: +1: This avoids the O(n²) time that might arise from my answer on non-indexed sequences. (On the other hand, it does consume the sequence and populate a new one, so I would prefer the OP's original code.)

Comment: @Douglas I think we all agree that OP's original code is the best/obvious/simplest solution to this problem :-)

Comment: @DominicKexel It does have me thinking though whether this type of problem could be generalized. I guess you could whittle it down to "something that needs a reverse iterator at x". Anyhow, I'll leave that to someone else if they're interested.